# Put a line break in a for loop that is generating html content

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop that is generating some HTML content:

```
var boxes = "";

for (i = 0; i < 11; i ++) {
    boxes += "<div class=\"box\"><img src=\"unlkd.png\"/></div>";
}

document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = boxes;
```

I want to display 3 boxes in one row, then below them 2 boxes in one row, then 1, then 3 again, 2, and 1.

First i thought of using the if statement to check whether i > 2 to add a line break, but it will also add a line break after every box past the third one. Nothing comes to mind, and my basic knowledge of javascript tells me I'll have to make a loop for each row I want to make. Any advice?

Comment: See [Remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

#### Idea

- Keep an array of batch size
- Loop over array and check if iterator is at par with position
- If yes, update position and index to fetch next position

```js
var boxes = "";
var intervals = [3, 2, 1];
var position = intervals[0];
var index = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  boxes += "<div class=\"box\"><img src=\"unlkd.png\"/></div>";
  if ((position-1) === i) {
    boxes += "<br/>";
    index = (index + 1) % intervals.length;
    position += intervals[index]
  }
}

document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = boxes;
```

```css
.box{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: This seems to work best for me. My boxes actually have a float: left property but instead of br i added a div with a clear:both property and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a different approch :

Use a array to store the number of item per row :

```
var array = [3, 2, 1, 3, 2];
```

Then, using two loops to iterate this

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    //Start the row 
    for(var j = 0; j < array[i]; ++j){
        //create the item inline
    }
    //End the row 
}
```

And you have a pretty system that will be dynamic if you load/update the array.

PS : not write javascript in a while, might be some syntax error

Edit :

To generate an id, this would be simple.

create a variable that will be used as a counter.

```
var counter = 0;
```

On each creating of an item, set the id like

```
var id = 'boxes_inline_' + counter++;
```

And add this value to the item you are generating.

Note : This is a small part of the algorithm I used to build a form generator. Of course the array contained much more values (properties). But this gave a really nice solution to build form depending on JSON

Comment: syntax -> array -> `[3,2,1,3,2]`

Comment: no worries, and your solution is clean if op needs limited repetitions.  :)

Comment: @AxelH Just a pointer, instead of repeating `[..., 3,2]`, use mod operator to repeat the pattern.

Comment: @Rajesh Well, I used this solution because, yes the actual pattern could be done with a modulo, but I stayed generic. If the patern become random, this would be simpler to maintain. And the pattern can be build with the modulo if needed ;)

Comment: Very elegant solution, however, having different id's for each box this creates boxes with same id's each row. I'm sorry that I didn't include that in my question, but this can come in handy too. Would you mind explaining what array.length does tho?

Comment: @MiloSx7 Well, you can use a counter to generate the ids easily. `array.length` is simply the number of cells in the array, so in your case, the number of row you want, and on each cell, the number of item you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var boxes = "",
    boxesInRow = 3,
    count = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 11; i ++) {
    boxes += "<div class=\"box\"><img src=\"unlkd.png\"/></div>";
    count++;
    if(count === boxesInRow) {
       boxes += "<br/>";
       boxesInRow -= 1;
       count = 0;
       if (boxesInRow === 0) {
           boxesInRow = 3;
       }
   }
}

document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = boxes;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var i;
    var boxes = "";
    for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        boxes += "<div class=""><img src=""/></div>";
        function displayboxes() {
        "use strict";
        for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            out.appendChild(document.createTextNode(boxes[i] + "<br>"));
        }
    }
        displayboxes(boxes);
```